# \ndk-build on Android native project failed. getting: process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ndk-build

C:\android-ndk\android-ndk-r26b\ndk-build -C C:\Users\AdnanChohan\Documents\MyProject\native

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.

make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/AdnanChohan/Documents/MyProject/native'
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-21.
jni/HostUnitTests.mk:19: pipe: No error
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:jni_latinime: non-system libraries in linker flags: -latomic
Android NDK:This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the current module

make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/AdnanChohan/Documents/MyProject/native'
make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/AdnanChohan/Documents/MyProject/native'
[x86] Install        : libjni_latinime.so => libs/x86/libjni_latinime.so
[x86_64] Install        : libjni_latinime.so => libs/x86_64/libjni_latinime.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libjni_latinime.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libjni_latinime.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libjni_latinime.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libjni_latinime.so
make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/AdnanChohan/Documents/MyProject/native'

ndk building process is getting failed and the "jni.so" files are not getting updated with the changes done to the code.

Running the following command on cmd:
ndk_path\ndk-build -C C:\Users\AdnanChohan\Documents\MyProject\native

Comment: `C:\Users\AdnanChohan\Documents\MyProject\native` <-- Is that the full path, or is there a space after "native" followed by additional characters? If you do have spaces in the path, get rid of them, because the NDK doesn't handle them well.

Comment: Yes this is the full path, Yes I know NDK does not handle spaces within the directory names. Thank you